# How do I url encode a date in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, url-encoding

I need to **url encode a date parameter** so I can send it to the api.

For example if I have a date `2013-08-01 00:00:00 +0000`, I need to send this through `2013-08-01+00%3a00%3a00+%2b0000`.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Convert it to an NSString, then urlencode that string as you would do with any parameter and then use that encoded string when you build up your url or you post parameters. Where exactly do you have an issue here? Can you share some code?

Comment: I'm doing exactly what Mundi suggested. I put in NSDate date and get 2013-08-08%2002:00:09%20+0200. The ":" are not url safe.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSDate *myDate; // this date should be encoded
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
df.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss ZZZ";
NSString *dateString = [df stringFromDate:myDate];
NSString *encodedDate = 
  [dateString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: I'm doing exactly that. I put in NSDate date and get 2013-08-08%2002:00:09%20+0200. The ":" are not url safe.

Answer (score 0):

This has always worked for me

```
NSString *encodedDate = (__bridge NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL, (CFStringRef)dateString, NULL, (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]", kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
```